# Get contents of element from external page PHP

Tags: php, html, css, external

I'd like to get the content (CSS, children, ect.) to display on a HTML page, but this element is on a external page. When I use:

```
$page = new DOMDocument();
$page->loadHTMLFile('about.php');
$text = $page->getElementById('text');
echo $text->nodeValue;
```

I only get the text, but `#text` also has a image as child and some CSS. Can I get (and echo) those to, kind of like with an iframe, but then with a element. If so, how?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Try using `.innerHTML()` method.

Comment: could you explain that?

Comment: `getElementById('text').innerHTML` [Explanation is here.](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp)

Comment: Yeah, I already took a look at that, but in all those examples JS is used instead of PHP. Could you please give a PHP-example as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe what you're looking for is [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php).

If you set the optional arguments it outputs only this particular node.

```
$elm = $page->getElementById('text');
echo $elm->ownerDocument->saveHTML($elm);
```

Comment: This does work, but in one om the children of `#text` contains some funky punctuation (like ï or é). When using your method, this copies as some weird combination: Ã¯. Any way of fixing this? Thanks a lot so far.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution, although it doesn't retrieve the CSS, but if you only need the element and its children, this is my best bet.

Use [simple_html_dom.php](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) to do all the hard stuff.

My external page:

```
<div id='text'>
    <img src='img/dummy.png' align='left' alt='Image not available. Our apologies.'/>
    <span>text</span><br/>
    <p>
        text
    </p>
    <p>
       text
    </p>
    <p>
        text
    </p>
<div>
```

Now, my page that I'd like to show the contents of my external page:

```
<?php include('../includes/simple_html_dom.php'); ?>
....
<?php
    $html = file_get_html('about.php');
    $ret = $html->find('div#text', 0);
    echo $ret;
?>
```

what this does, it echos the element with its children, without CSS unfortunately.